# How to search keywords, filtered by - most popular, in (x) years/months on YouTube or Google search?

Tags: youtube, google-search, search

How to search YouTube (or via search engine like Google to reach YouTube) keywords, filtered by - most popular, in (x) years/months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Youtube**
First type your keywords and click search. After getting the results of your search, you can then sort by clicking the filter options and selecting options related to dates, sort by "View count" for popularity.

You can also use the `before` and `after` keywords to restrict the range of search. For example, to search from videos from February 2020, type: `before:2020-03-01 after:2020-01-31`.

[image: IMG:]

**From Google Search**

Type your keyboard followed by `site:youtube.com` to restrict the search to only youtube. You can then click on Tools to display more options. You can customize the date range and the duration. The begore and after options also work with Google Search.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Men i can't say how thankful I'm in first place, to find this kind of answers is like finding unicorn. Now when i found one myself, i would like to hold you for a minute, and ask, where you yourself learn these kind of things, maybe link to some kind of articles or something? I would love to learn, everything what is deeper then the surface, about in first place 'Medicles' for Youtube and search engines. This forum defiantly goes to first step for me.

Comment: Google `google-fu`.